# Can't create a file in the server with Filestreams .NET

Tags: c#, .net, server, filestream, streamwriter

What i am trying to do is to Create or writea text file in the server to work as a data log, this code works fine in my pc, but when i build the solution and upload the server files, it creates nothing. Could it be that this code only appends the data and as it doesn't find the file, it doesn't do anything?

```
string fileName= HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\logs.txt");

using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Append))
{
  using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(SourceStream))
  {
     file.WriteLine(data);
  }
}
```

I also checked the server folder permissions and it is ok

Am i missing something?
is something wrong?
something that could be done better?

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, what is the error?

Comment: that's the point, i don't get anything, all i know that the file is not being created

Comment: The code you have there will throw an exception, there are tons of them depending on what goes wrong. Either the file is getting written in some other location or an exception is being thrown that you're swallowing elsewhere.

Comment: Can you log the location of `fileName` somewhere so you can see where it is going?

Answer (score 2):

You should give write Permission to your IIS application pool, so your application can write file on directory.
On local, application has this permission by default but on server you should give this permission manually.

Comment: did you test it on other directory of your app like `~/Content`?

Comment: i tried with another directories but again, nothing

Comment: So if you are not getting any error may file is creating but you cant see it because of your config of server or your host Control Panel.

How do you check is file created or not?